# How get the special-use attributes for IMAP mailboxes using Indy?

Tags: delphi, imap, indy, indy10

RFC 6154, "IMAP LIST Extension for Special-Use Mailboxes", states that the results of the `LIST` command should contain special-use attributes for each listed mailbox.

In Indy's `TIdMailBoxAttributes`, however, I don't find them. They ought to be `/All`, `/Archived`, `/Draft`, etc., but I see `Noinferiors`, `Noselect`, etc.

Obviously these are different attributes.

How do I access these special-use attributes?

---

Update after a bit of source-diving:
I assume this is easily achieved by expanding the `MailBoxAttributes` constant in the `IdMailBox` unit and consequently altering the  `IdIMAP4.ParseMailBoxAttributeString` method in `IdIMAP4`?

Comment: What server are you connecting to?

Comment: @legoscia ATM, I'm testing on a Google server.

Answer (score 2):

Indy's `TIdIMAP4` and `TIdIMAP4Server` components do not support the special-use attributes yet.  There are open tickets for that feature in Indy's issue trackers:

Add support for IMAP LIST Extension for Special-Use Mailboxes
http://code.google.com/p/indyproject/issues/detail?id=257
http://indy.codeplex.com/workitem/24462

Comment: Thanks, Remy. If I'd need them today, was my tinkering suggestion pointing in the right direction?

Comment: `ParseMailBoxAttributeString()` is not currently used by `InternalParseListResult()` (in fact, `ParseMailBoxAttributeString()` is not being used at all), so you would have to add that, as well as find a place to store the parsed attributes (which is the main reason why Indy has not implemented this yet). And you would have to update `ListMailBoxes()`, `ListInferiorMailBoxes()`, and `ListSubscribedMailBoxes()` to include a `RETURN (SPECIAL-USE)` clause on the `LIST` command (only when the `CAPABILITY` response includes `SPECIAL-USE`) in order to retrieve the attributes for parsing.

Comment: I see this feature was proposed in 2013. Can I bump it up the list by voting for it a couple of times somewhere? ;)

Comment: Both tracker systems have a voting system (Google Code is [closing soon](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html), though). You can bump the vote count all you want, that doesn't mean I will have spare time to get around to implementing it. I'll get to it when I can.The main reason I haven't already implementing it is because it would likely require an `interface` change, which prevents Embarcadero from including Indy updates in RADStudio service packs (although I do occasionally ignore that and make interface changes anyway!).

Comment: Understand the time issue; you're performing miracles as it is. I'll just try to glue something together to get the info from the server, that'll hopefully hold up until it gets implemented in Indy. Thanks!